# Real current directory

Tags: pwd, readlink

Obviously I know about `pwd` and `readlink`, but is there a command to find out the *real* absolute path to the current directory (ie, resolving links and dots)?

Comment: Whats up with readlink ?

Comment: @123 Resolving links is sort of the point of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pwd -P
```

(in any POSIX shell), is the command you're looking for.

`-P` is for *physical* (as opposed to *logical* (`-L`, the default) where `pwd` mostly dumps the content of `$PWD` (which the shell maintains based on the arguments you give to `cd` or `pushd`)).

```
$ ln -s . /tmp/here
$ cd /tmp/here/here
$ cd ../here/here
$ pwd
/tmp/here/here/here
$ pwd -P
/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$ env pwd
```

Or

```
$ /bin/pwd
```

Unless the variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, in which case you need to add `-P`.

---

The details:

The shell has a builtin called `pwd` which defaults to printing the value of shell's `$PWD`. In doing so, it may include *logical* paths (a default `-L`).

If you call the builtin with (`-P`) or use the external `/bin/pwd`:

```
$ ln -s . /tmp/here; cd /tmp/here/here/here

$ pwd
/tmp/here/here/here

$ pwd -P
/tmp

$ /bin/pwd 
/tmp
```

The reason is that the external `/bin/pwd` defaults to the `-P` option.
From `info pwd`:

> this implementation uses `-P' as the default unless the`POSIXLY_CORRECT' environment variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python also works:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.path.realpath('.'))"
```

Comment: Seems a little heavyweight to me to start a Python interpreter just to get the current path...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling :) Hence the question, but it turns out that RTFM was the answer to my question.. sorry about this!

Comment: `getcwd()` from any language should work, no need to resort to `realpath`. The shell's interface to `getcwd()` is the `pwd` command, but by default, shells replace getcwd with a _fancy_ version that tries to give some information on how you got there, hence the need for `-P` there. Other languages don't have that problem, so you can use their `getcwd()` there like `os.getcwd()` for `python`.